Is sequential diazotization of benzene possible?
I am trying to diazotize one of the nitro groups in 1,3-dinitro-5-bromobenzene while leaving the other as NO2. I'm trying to sequentially diazotize them and perform a Sandmeyer to add two different substitute groups, but I'm a little stuck on whether this sequential diazotization is even possible.
This is just for a theoretical synthesis, but I was curious if this is feasible in reality, and if so what types of conditions would be necessary. I tried looking at existing literature on this but couldn't find anything pertaining to this topic, thank you!

You cannot diazotize nitro groups. You first have to reduce to aniline. It is possible to selectively reduce nitro groups in poly-nitrated benzene with NaSH
